# Pygame my enemy class disappears after movement

Tags: python, class, pygame

The code works fine when you first load the game the two rectangles are there but when the player moves, the enemy rectangle disappears.

EXTENSION I am trying to get the enemy class to move up and down constantly without any keys needed to be pressed.

```
import pygame
import os 
import random 
from pygame.locals import * # Constants
import math
import sys
import random

pygame.init()  

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720)) #(length,height)
screen_rect=screen.get_rect()
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = pygame.image.load('stage.png').convert()
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,128), (50,560,50,25)) #(colour)(x-position,y-position,width,height)
        self.dist = 100

    def draw_rect(self,x,y):    # This is my code which should make the player move
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0)) #If this isn't included then when the rectangle moves it's old positon will still be on the screen
        self.rect = self.rect.move(x*self.dist, y*self.dist); pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 128), self.rect)
        pygame.display.update()

    def handle_keys(self): # code to make the character move when the arrow keys are pressed
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.draw_rect(-0.05,0)
        elif keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.draw_rect(0.05,0)
        elif keys[K_UP]:
            self.draw_rect(0,-0.05)
        elif keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.draw_rect(0,0.05)
        elif keys[K_SPACE]:
            self.draw_rect(0.05,-0.05)
        if self.rect.right > 1280:
            self.rect.right = 1280
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > 720:
            self.rect.bottom = 720
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite): # the enemy class which works fine
    def __init__(self):
        x = random.randint(50,450)
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (128,0,0), (300,x,50,25))


player = Player()
enemy = Enemy()

def main():  #my main loop 
    running = True
    while running:
        player.handle_keys()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        pygame.display.flip()   #updates the whole screen

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking at implementing a simple state machine for your enemy movements. Use a timer to periodically update the enemy position in the state machine. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. You can post a new question regarding the enemy movement, but you should try to implement it on your own first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear the screen every frame - you can do this by blitting the background - and draw the sprites afterwards. Separate the movement from the drawing code so that you can blit the sprites after the screen has been cleared.

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,128), (50,560,50,25))
        self.dist = 100

    # Separate the movement and the drawing.
    def move(self, x, y):
        self.rect = self.rect.move(x*self.dist, y*self.dist)

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 128), self.rect)

    def handle_keys(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.move(-0.05,0)
        elif keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.move(0.05,0)
        elif keys[K_UP]:
            self.move(0,-0.05)
        elif keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.move(0,0.05)
        elif keys[K_SPACE]:
            self.move(0.05,-0.05)
        if self.rect.right > 1280:
            self.rect.right = 1280
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > 720:
            self.rect.bottom = 720
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0


class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(50,450)  # x is now an attribute.

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (128,0,0), (300, self.x, 50, 25))


def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
    player = Player()
    enemy = Enemy()

    running = True
    while running:
        player.handle_keys()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        # Clear the screen every frame by blitting the background.
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        # Then draw the enemy and the player.
        enemy.draw(screen)
        player.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.
```

I also recommend checking out how sprite groups work, then you can get rid of the `draw` methods and can just call `sprite_group.draw(screen)` to draw every contained sprite. Here's a [tutorial](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=en#section_13).

Answer (score 1):

you are only drawing the sprites when the class is instatiated in the `__init__()`

you need to be drawing them every loop in the `main()`function right before `pygame.display.flip()`

as things are right now, neither the player nor the enemy should display beyond the first frame